# Keflavik car hire shuttle bus service timetable

Tags: airports, car-rentals, iceland

At Keflavik Airport, only four main car hire companies have their offices inside the Airport building; for the other ones, there is a shuttle bus service operating. Since I'll be arriving quite early at the airport to drop my car off (around 5 am), I was wondering if there is already a shuttle bus service this early, and if yes, when/how often it runs. Unfortunately, there is absolutely no information about this service on either the [homepage of Keflavik Airport](http://www.kefairport.is/english/to-and-from-the-airport/car-hire/), nor on the sites of some the car hire companies which are out of the airport (like Alamo).

Does anyone know anything about this service?

Comment: No first hand experience with this but there are **a lot** of flights that arrive/depart KEF between 5 and 8 each morning. Its the busiest time of day. I'd be surprised if the shuttle service wasn't running during the busiest hours.

Comment: We rented from SAD cars last September.  Their traffic volume was small enough that the shuttle ran basically whenever someone showed up to drop off a car.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So some first hand experience: the shuttle bus does operate fine around 5am, and it departs from each location around every 15 minutes

Comment: Did you find out when it started/finished?

Comment: @CMaster unfortunately no. Talking to other passengers it looks like it was already working at 4am